# CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE using Intel Core 2 Duo E8500 CPU

Tags: opencl, intel

I get the error `CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE` when running [this sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15499533/1397061).  However, unlike in that question, my CPU, the Intel Core 2 Duo E8500 CPU, appears to be [supported](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-release-notes#2).  I've made sure to link against the Intel version of the OpenCL libraries, since I also have the Nvidia libraries installed.  Why is this error occurring?

Comment: Have you tried AMD's OpenCL platform for the Intel chip?  I've always been able to use the AMD platform with Intel processors, perhaps this will work?  If not, are you getting the same error?

Comment: @Austin I haven't yet, because I assumed that CodeXL / CodeXL Plugin for Visual Studio wouldn't support debugging on an Intel CPU, because it doesn't support debugging on Nvidia GPUs.  Do you know whether AMD supports debugging on Intel CPUs?

Comment: I don't, sorry.  I do debugging in other ways. It would be interesting if the same error is reported by the AMD platform though.

Comment: @Austin What other ways?  The easiest way I've found so far is to pass a buffer into the kernel and print or debug it CPU-side after the kernel returns.

Comment: I wrote an add-on for LabVIEW (OpenCLV) that let's me visualize stuff really easily.  It is pretty easy to debug my kernels that way.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: @Austin Unfortunately not.  I'm using a different computer now with Intel Integrated Graphics, and it works, but I still can't debug.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.  What bugs are you running into?  Is it a super complex kernel?

Comment: @Austin It's hard to tell since the problems don't manifest themselves until the kernel finishes, but likely memory access violations on the device.

Comment: Yeah, if you are doing differentials and kernel type work, it is usually best to try and either use the Global Offset (doesn't work on a lot of NVIDIA) and or test each global_thread_id() and make sure it is within the bounds of memory.

Intel processors also crash when the memory overflows, if you can use an ATI or NVIDIA card, they don't tend to crash and you can get SOME useful info out of it.

Comment: @Austin.. How and/or from where can I install AMD OpenCL platform for Intel Chip? I am using Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T6500  @ 2.10GHz with Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE" has nothing to do with the SDK.  It's due to the OpenCL device driver which is part of the video card device driver.

It's common to confuse the SDK and the OpenCL device driver.  You develop the host code with the SDK but the kernel is compiled and run through the device driver.  I often develop with the Intel SDK but I run my kernels on the CPU using the Intel video driver or the AMD Radeon drivers and on the GPU using the Nvidia video drivers (GTX590).  I have all three video drivers installed in Windows.  You don't have to have an AMD video card to instal the Radeon drivers.

So in your case you can use the AMD drivers to run your kernel on the CPU.  They are much less restrictive than Intel's.

On windows I get faster results running my Kernel on my Sandy Bridge CPU using the Intel OpenCL drivers than AMD.  However, on Linux the AMD driver runs my kernel faster on my Intel CPU than the Intel driver does.

Comment: I installed the AMD APP CPU SDK Runtime from the [AMD APP SDK](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/), but AMD doesn't show up as a platform, only Nvidia, and my Intel CPU does not show up as a device.  What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I meant install the AMD video drivers.  OpenCL runs through your video drivers.  Intel's video driver does not support your CPU for OpenCL.

Comment: I also tried installing the [AMD Catalyst Display Driver](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/windows/Pages/radeonaiw_win8-64.aspx), but the AMD Catalyst Install Manager does not even give installing the display driver as an option.

Comment: Strange.  It installed for me on Windows and I have an Intel CPU and a Nvidia GPU.  I installed it on several systems without AMD products.  I have not used it for several months.  Maybe they changed it now so that it requires either an AMD CPU or GPU?  That would not be surprising.

Comment: @1'', I just noticed on Intel's OpenCL SDK [page](http://software.intel.com/en-us/vcsource/tools/opencl-sdk) the statement "The SDK also supports OpenCL on the CPU with older versions of Intel® Core™ processors (including 1st and 2nd generation). On these platforms a CPU only OpenCL runtime is available. (Download [here](http://registrationcenter.intel.com/irc_nas/3044/intel_sdk_for_ocl_applications_2013_runtime_setup.exe)".  You have a 1st generation core processor.  Maybe that will help.

Comment: The CPU only runtime comes bundled with the SDK.  I'm not sure why they even offer it as a separate download.  Is there a different way it's supposed to be used for older processors?

Comment: I think they offer it separate for people who just want to run OpenCL on the CPU and don't need an Intel video driver.  I'm still surprised a bit the AMD video drivers won't install.  I guess AMD figured out people were using their OpenCL drivers for Intel CPUs and decided to stop it.  Intel already cripples ICC, MKL,...when it does not detect an Intel CPU.

Comment: Are you getting the download from their drivers page? It wants to know which Radeon card you're using. Will this make any difference for the OpenCL driver installed?

Answer (score 3):

The Intel OpenCL SDK 2013 required SSE 4.2. From what I can tell ([here](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Core_2/Intel-Core%202%20Duo%20E8500%20EU80570PJ0876M%20-%20AT80570PJ0876M%20%28BX80570E8500%29.html)) the Intel Core 2 Duo E8500 CPU only has SSE 4.1

"CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE" is the error you get when you try to create an OpenCL device on an unsupported CPU.

The good news for you is that the Intel OpenCL SDK 2012 works on SSE 4.1; you should uninstall the 2013 SDK and use the 2012 SDK instead (or get a newer CPU).

Comment: Right, my link was to the 2012 release notes.  Thanks for clarifying!  Unfortunately, the 2012 version doesn't support OpenCL 1.2, so no printf and other goodies.

Comment: @1'' You can install the AMD Radeon video drivers (even if you don't have a AMD video card) and run your kernel on the CPU with the AMD driver.  It supports OpenCL 1.2 as well.  Your SDK is not the problem.

Comment: @redrum Thanks so much, I'm now able to run OpenCL, and even use `printf()`, on my old Intel CPU!

Comment: @1'', Glad I could help :-)  What did you do in the end to get it working?

Comment: @redrum I just had to install the AMD drivers and reboot a couple of times so it would show up as an OpenCL platform.

Comment: @1'', so you manged to install the Catalyst driver after all?  That's good news.

Comment: @redrum You know, funny enough, I don't think I ever installed more than the Catalyst Install Manager.  Perhaps it actually installed the driver behind the scenes but didn't tell me?  Ah well.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error while creating a tutorial on how to install hashcat on Ubuntu 18.04; I've included the instructions below for Installing OpenCL™ Runtimes for Intel® Processors - Option A (Recommended)- feel free to review my [full gist on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/alexanderjsingleton/d00a56a51127e73b70a2cdffcd75c9e2).  Hope that helps!

### Installing OpenCL™ Runtimes for Intel® Processors

#### Installing OpenCL™ Runtimes for Intel® Processors - Option A (Recommended)

1. Check your CPU system processor architecture by running `sudo lscpu` to identify the class of CPU e.g. "Intel (R) Core (TM) i7-7700 CPU @ 3.60Ghz"- alternatively, you can go to Settings > Details which will also reveal the CPU-family (e.g. Intel (R) HD Graphics 630 (Kaby Lake GT2)).
2. Go to the [Intel Developer Zone](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers#graph-lin-ubuntu) and scroll down to the corresponding download link for your system; assuming you're running Ubuntu 18.04 and have a Intel Core-class CPU, scroll down to "Linux* OS Ubuntu* 16.04.x (deb)" and click on the [Github link for 18.46.11837 Runtimes](https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases) to access the runtime-packages to download.
3. There should be instructions within the aforementioned Github repo- or you can proceed with the following in the next steps.
4. `cd ~/Desktop`
5. `mkdir neo`
6. `cd neo`
7. `sudo wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/18.46.11837/intel-gmmlib_18.4.0.348_amd64.deb`
8. `wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/18.46.11837/intel-igc-core_18.44.1060_amd64.deb`
9. `wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/18.46.11837/intel-igc-opencl_18.44.1060_amd64.deb`
10. `wget https://github.com/intel/compute-runtime/releases/download/18.46.11837/intel-opencl_18.46.11837_amd64.deb`
11. Install the packages by running `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`.
12. Restart the system by running `sudo reboot`.

#### Installing OpenCL™ Runtimes for Intel® Processors - Option B

1. Go to [Intel OpenCL Runtimes website](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers) and scroll down to the bottom of the page to Download Intel CPU Runtime for OpenCL Applications 18.1 for LINUX OS (64-bit only).
2. After downloading the OpenCL Runtimes for Intel Processors, `cd ~/Downloads`
3. Run `sudo tar -xzf l_opencl_p_18.1.0.013.tgz` to unpack the tgz file- please note, the OpenCL file version may update since the time as of this gist (ie as of this gist, the version is 18.1.0.013.)
4. `cd l_opencl_p_18.1.0.013`
5. Run `sudo ./install.sh`
6. A welcome screen is prompted- hold-down the "Enter" key until able to input select "2" for "I do NOT consent to the collection of my Information"
7. Hit "1"
8. Hit "1"
9. Hit "Enter" and then restart the computer.
10. If any additional Intel OpenCL errors are encountered after testing hashcat, go to section 'Installing OpenCL™ Runtimes for Intel® Processors - B'- if not, proceed with section "Testing Hashcat"