# intel kernel builder, failed to create context for intel opencl cpu device

Tags: windows, kernel, opencl, intel, builder

I'm trying to use intel kernel builder. I installed intel opencl sdk and execute the program. Type easy code like this.

```
__kernel void hello(__global int* a, __global int* b, __global int* c) {
  int gid = get_global_id(0);
  c[gid] = a[gid] + b[gid];
}
```

I pressed the compile or build button but it showed me an error. The error message is.

*Using default instruction set architecture.
Failed to create context for Intel OpenCL CPU device...
Compilation failed!*

I found someone is suffering from the similar problem.
http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/392622
But there's no proper answer in this question.

I think the code is not a main problem of this. So I erase the code and remain only one character and then compiled it. The error message is same as before. I have no idea what the matter is.

My environment is Windows7 Professional 64bits, intel Core2 Quad Q8200 which support SSE4.1, OpenCL-1.2-3.0.67279 intel_sdk_2013_x64, kernel builder version 3.0.0.1. 
And I have never run OpenCL in this machine. I tried but compilation error occured. The error message is similar. They failed to create context. The code may have no problem since I've run it in another machine and OS(linux).

If there's someone who use this program, please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this Site, Intels OpenCL SDK does not support Core2 Duo/Quad CPUs (because they do not support SSe 4.2):
http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdk-for-opencl-applications-2013-release-notes#_System_Requirements_1

So the compiler cannot create the context for this device. You may be able to work around this by explicitly choosing the target architecture in the Option Dialog. I'm not sure this will work and the code will certainly not run.

If you want to use OpenCL on you machine, try the AMD APP SDK, which supports every x86 with at least SSE2:
http://developer.amd.com/tools/heterogeneous-computing/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/

That, however, will not work with Intel's KernelBuilder.

Comment: It's not the SDK that's the problem.  It's the the OpenCL client driver.  You can still develop with the Intel OpenCL SDK and run OpenCL though the AMD OpenCL device driver. [cl-device-not-available-using-intel-core-2-duo-e8500-cpu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193320/cl-device-not-available-using-intel-core-2-duo-e8500-cpu/18404235#18404235)

Comment: Will you also be able to compile code with the "Intel KernelBuilder - AMD CPU OpenCL Driver" combination? On Linux, that directly calls the Intel compiler.

Comment: In fact, I want binary code of the kernel which produced by intel's OpenCL. But on linux(A server which support sse4.2), the binary format it not elf($file <binary> command says the format is 'data'). So objdump command cannot decode the binary. I find and saw Kernel Builder which easily decode the binary to assembly and alternatively tried it on local machine. But I faced the problem and you guys help me to resolve it. Now I'll just use other's machine. Thanks a lot for your help by heart. I really appreciate it.