# How to install AMD Video Drivers for Intel Core 2 Duo - (OpenCL requirement.)

Tags: opencl, intel, amd-gpu

My Laptop does not have any Graphic Card. It is a simple Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T6500  @ 2.10GHz with Ubuntu 15.10. I want to work with OpenCL 1.2. I Installed the Ubuntu version of OpenCL from here  https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/opencl/topic/390630.

Now if I run the 'clinfo' command in Terminal, it gives me:

```
Number of platforms :   1
```

and the rest of the info about the platform. Till this part, it's working fine.

But then I followed some simple codes to learn OpenCL from https://github.com/HandsOnOpenCL. I try to run any example and it gives me the following error.

```
Exception
ERROR: clCreateContextFromType(CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE)
```

I followed the error and found out through this [CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE using Intel Core 2 Duo E8500 CPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18193320/cl-device-not-available-using-intel-core-2-duo-e8500-cpu) that my CPU does not support OpenCL. In the comments section, they have discussed that alternatively AMD video drivers could be used to run OpenCL...

What is the exact procedure for downloading and installing AMD Video drivers for Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU T6500 @ 2.10GHz with Ubuntu 15.10? Is there any tutorial that I can follow? Do I have to install the Catalyst?

Comment: That question does not seem to make any sense. You are asking how to install _video_ driver for a _CPU_? You need to have corresponding device in your system in order to install a driver, in this case, AMD video card.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to install AMD-APP-SDK which stands for *AMD OpenCL™ Accelerated Parallel Processing SDK*.

The installation procedure is very simple:

`sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev`

Download `AMD-APP-SDKInstaller-v3.0.130.135-GA-linux64.tar.bz2` from [here](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/) and install.

`sudo reboot`

Comment: I followed the link, downloaded v2.9. And it worked like a charm. One small question though... I have two platforms now. One is AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing the other is Intel OpenCL(which is pretty useless now). Is there a way to Uninstall OpenCL. And would it affect any of my codes/headers/libraries etc.? Or should I just keep it there?

Comment: Link in your description suggests you installed Intel OpenCL from deb using dpkg then uninstall it by: `sudo dpkg -r <name>`, for example `sudo dpkg -r opencl-1.2-intel-cpu`. Removing them shouldn't not break anything.